# How extract array elements in json

Tags: java, json

I want to extract the array elements starting from "results" as shown in the following JSON response:

```
    {
  "bossresponse":{
    "responsecode":"200",
    "web":{
      "start":"0",
      "count":"42",
      "totalresults":"89200000",
      "results":[
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/www.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/www.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"www.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>!",
          "abstract":"Welcome to <b>Yahoo<\/b>!, the world's most visited home page. Quickly find what you're searching for, get in touch with friends and stay in-the-know with the latest news and ..."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/mail.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/mail.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"mail.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"Sign in to <b>Yahoo<\/b>!",
          "abstract":"Your World. Your Way. <b>Yahoo<\/b>! makes it easy to enjoy what matters most in your world. Best in class <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Mail, breaking local, national and global news, finance ..."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/groups.yahoo.com\/?ch=web&pub=fp-us&t=fp&sec=link&slk=defaultrough",
          "url":"http:\/\/groups.yahoo.com\/?ch=web&pub=fp-us&t=fp&sec=link&slk=defaultrough",
          "dispurl":"groups.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com\/?ch=web&pub=fp-us&t=fp&sec=link&slk=...",
          "title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Groups - Join or create groups, clubs, forums ...",
          "abstract":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Groups offers free mailing lists, photo & file sharing, group calendars and more. Discuss hot topics, share interests, join online communities."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/homes.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/homes.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"homes.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Homes - Home for Sale and Rent, Makeovers, Design and ...",
          "abstract":"Some <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Homes information is provided by our trusted partners. However, <b>Yahoo<\/b>! does not guarantee the accuracy or completeness of any third party content."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Yahoo",
          "url":"http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Yahoo",
          "dispurl":"en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/<b>Yahoo<\/b>",
          "title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia",
          "abstract":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Inc. (NASDAQ: YHOO) is an American multinational internet corporation headquartered in Sunnyvale, California, United States. The company is best known for its ..."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/taxes.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/taxes.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"taxes.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Finance - Personal Finance | Taxes",
          "abstract":"Taxes - Read latest articles and guides, try our comprehensive calculators, tools, and get advice at <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Finance"
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/omg.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/omg.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"omg.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"omg! Celebrity gossip, news photos, babies, couples, hotties ...",
          "abstract":"The latest celebrity gossip from <b>Yahoo<\/b>! omg! Get the latest news and gossip on the Hollywood celebrities with videos and photos."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/uk.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/uk.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"uk.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! UK",
          "abstract":"Welcome to <b>Yahoo<\/b>!, the world's most visited home page. Quickly find what you're searching for, get in touch with friends and stay in-the-know with the latest news and ..."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/smallbusiness.yahoo.com\/?s_fptrough=ysb_acq_smallbiz_20081001",
          "url":"http:\/\/smallbusiness.yahoo.com\/?s_fptrough=ysb_acq_smallbiz_20081001",
          "dispurl":"smallbusiness.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com\/?s_fptrough=ysb_acq_smallbiz...",
          "title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Small Business: Web Hosting, Domain Registration, E ...",
          "abstract":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Small Business provides reliable web hosting for your website, domain name registration, web site design templates, e-commerce solutions for your ..."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/cricket.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/cricket.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"cricket.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Cricket - Live Cricket Score | Cricket News | Cricket ...",
          "abstract":"Check out live cricket scores, cricket news headlines, cricket schedules & results and more from <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Cricket Includes ICC World Cricket League Championship 2012 ..."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/messenger.yahoo.com\/?i=1",
          "url":"http:\/\/messenger.yahoo.com\/?i=1",
          "dispurl":"messenger.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com\/?i=1",
          "title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Messenger - Chat, Instant message, SMS, Video Call, PC ...",
          "abstract":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Messenger - Chat with friends for free and enjoy stealth settings, video calls, PC calls, file sharing, photo sharing, SMS, emoticons, & more."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/uk.my.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/uk.my.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"uk.my.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"My <b>Yahoo<\/b>! - <b>Yahoo<\/b>! UK",
          "abstract":"My <b>Yahoo<\/b>! is a customisable web page from <b>Yahoo<\/b>! UK. Personalise your page by adding news, stock quotes, weather, email, social updates and much more."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/search.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/search.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"search.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Search - Web Search",
          "abstract":"Learn about the new <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Axis. A better way to search. Way better. Get it Now! >>"
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/news.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/news.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"news.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! News - Latest News & Headlines",
          "abstract":"The latest news and headlines from <b>Yahoo<\/b>! News. Get breaking news stories and in-depth coverage with videos and photos."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/au.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/au.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"au.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>!7",
          "abstract":"The <b>Yahoo<\/b>! for Australia offering local & global search, free email, instant messaging, news, sport, travel, shopping, movies & music."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/ca.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/ca.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"ca.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Canada",
          "abstract":"Welcome to <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Canada, the world's most visited home page. Quickly find what you're searching for, get in touch with friends and stay in-the-know with the latest ..."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/everything.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/everything.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"everything.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>!",
          "abstract":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! International ... © 2012 <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Inc. All rights reserved"
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/football.fantasysports.yahoo.com\/?ovchn=YAH&ovcpn=Front+Page&ovcrn=Front+page+P+Link+Nav+button&ovrfd=YAH&ovtac=AD",
          "url":"http:\/\/football.fantasysports.yahoo.com\/?ovchn=YAH&ovcpn=Front+Page&ovcrn=Front+page+P+Link+Nav+button&ovrfd=YAH&ovtac=AD",
          "dispurl":"football.fantasysports.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com\/?ovchn=YAH&ovcpn=Front...",
          "title":"It's Game Time! - <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Sports Fantasy Football",
          "abstract":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Fantasy Football. Create or join a NFL league and manage your team with FREE live scoring, stats, scouting reports, news, and expert advice."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/music.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/music.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"music.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Music - Exclusive New Music and Music Videos",
          "abstract":"Find all the new music and exclusive video performances on <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Music. Get the latest news in our exclusive music blogs, listen to our online music radio and catch ..."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/uk.messenger.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/uk.messenger.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"uk.messenger.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Messenger - Chat, Instant message, Video Call, PC Calls",
          "abstract":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Messenger - Chat with friends for free and enjoy stealth settings, video calls, PC calls, file sharing, photo sharing, emoticons, & more."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/in.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/in.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"in.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! India",
          "abstract":"Welcome to <b>Yahoo<\/b>!, the world's most visited home page. Quickly find what you're searching for, get in touch with friends and stay in-the-know with the latest news and ..."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/companion.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/companion.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"companion.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Toolbar - Stay in touch with your world.",
          "abstract":"Toolbar for <b>Yahoo<\/b>! search, alerts for <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Mail and an option to save bookmarks online."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/movies.yahoo.com\/photos\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/movies.yahoo.com\/photos\/",
          "dispurl":"movies.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com\/photos",
          "title":"Movie Pictures | Movie Posters - <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Movies",
          "abstract":"View movie pictures and stills from the latest releases on <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Movies. Find movie posters, red carpet photos and pictures from upcoming movies."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/local.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/local.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"local.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"Redmond City Pages on <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Local. Find Businesses, Services ...",
          "abstract":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Local has Redmond business reviews, top rated services, and events near Redmond, WA. Use interactive maps, driving directions reviews and ratings to find the ..."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/yahooligans.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/yahooligans.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"<b>yahoo<\/b>ligans.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"Kids Games, Kids Movies, Kids Music, and More - <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Kids",
          "abstract":"<b>Yahoo<\/b> Kids! is the ultimate web guide for kids! Features fun and educational resources for kids with games, animals, music, jokes, movies, news, astrology, TV ..."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/m.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/m.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"m.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Mobile",
          "abstract":"Welcome to <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Mobile. Stay up to date on the go with business, sports, and entertainment news."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/tv.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/tv.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"tv.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! TV",
          "abstract":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! TV is your guide to everything about TV online, from TV show listings and episode guides, to the latest TV show photos, clips, news, recaps, cast & credits ..."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/shopping.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/shopping.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"shopping.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Shopping - Online Shopping with great products, prices ...",
          "abstract":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Shopping is the best place to read user reviews, explore great products and buy online."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/dir.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/dir.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"dir.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Directory",
          "abstract":"Help us improve the <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Directory - Share your ideas"
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/overview.mail.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/overview.mail.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"overview.mail.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Mail",
          "abstract":"Your favorite email is now: FASTER: 2x faster. How great is that? So great. SAFER: Even better spam protection. Yes! EASIER: Clean, simple design that makes email a ..."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/travel.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/travel.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"travel.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Travel - Cheap flights, hotels, travel guides & car rental",
          "abstract":"Find cheap flights, hotels and car rentals with <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Travel. Plan your trip with travel guides, personalized recommendations, articles, deals and more."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/omg.yahoo.com\/news\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/omg.yahoo.com\/news\/",
          "dispurl":"omg.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com\/news",
          "title":"Celebrity News | Celebrity Gossip - <b>Yahoo<\/b>! omg!",
          "abstract":"Get the latest celebrity news from <b>Yahoo<\/b>! omg! Find the latest news about the Hollywood celebrities with videos and photos"
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/games.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/games.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"games.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Games - Play Free Online Games | Download Games",
          "abstract":"Play the latest online games on <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Games. Play and download single and multiplayer games from a wide selection of arcade, board and puzzle games."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/omg.yahoo.com\/photos\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/omg.yahoo.com\/photos\/",
          "dispurl":"omg.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com\/photos",
          "title":"Celebrity Photos | Pictures of Celebrities - <b>Yahoo<\/b>! omg!",
          "abstract":"View the latest celebrity photos on <b>Yahoo<\/b>! omg! Get the latest red carpet pictures and photos from Hollywood."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/finance.yahoo.com\/q?s=",
          "url":"http:\/\/finance.yahoo.com\/q?s=",
          "dispurl":"finance.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com\/q?s=",
          "title":"Quotes &amp; Info- <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Finance",
          "abstract":"View the basic stock chart on <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Finance. Change the date range, chart type and compare against other companies."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/movies.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/movies.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"movies.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Movies - Upcoming Movies, Trailers and Showtimes",
          "abstract":"View the latest trailers and movie reviews on <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Movies. Find everything about movies online, from upcoming releases, movie ratings, trailers and movie news"
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/screen.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/screen.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"screen.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"Watch videos online - <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Screen",
          "abstract":"Watch videos online for free on <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Screen. Find sports, kids and funny videos including the latest news video clips."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/privacy.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/privacy.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"privacy.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Privacy Policy",
          "abstract":"WHAT THIS PRIVACY POLICY COVERS <b>Yahoo<\/b>! takes your privacy seriously. Please read the following to learn more about our privacy policy. The federal ..."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/news.yahoo.com\/us\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/news.yahoo.com\/us\/",
          "dispurl":"news.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com\/us",
          "title":"U.S. News Headlines - <b>Yahoo<\/b>! News",
          "abstract":"Get the latest U.S. news headlines from <b>Yahoo<\/b>! News. Find breaking U.S. news, including analysis and opinion on top U.S. stories."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/fantasysports.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/fantasysports.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"fantasysports.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"Fantasy on <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Sports - News, Scores, Standings, Rumors ...",
          "abstract":"Comprehensive Fantasy news, scores, standings, fantasy games, rumors, and more"
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/finance.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/finance.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"finance.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Finance - Business Finance, Stock Market, Quotes, News",
          "abstract":"At <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Finance, you get free stock quotes, up to date news, portfolio management resources, international market data, message boards, and mortgage ..."
        },
        {
          "date":"",
          "clickurl":"http:\/\/world.yahoo.com\/",
          "url":"http:\/\/world.yahoo.com\/",
          "dispurl":"world.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com",
          "title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>!: <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Everywhere",
          "abstract":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! USA (en Español) ... © 2012 <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Inc. All rights reserved"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I used the following lines:

```
  JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
  JsonObject linksObj =  jsonParser.parse(jsonReader).getAsJsonObject();
  JsonArray linksArray = jsonParser.parse(linksObj.get("results").toString()).getAsJsonArray();
```

But I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at parseResponse.main(parseResponse.java:35)
```

When I tried to remove the text prior to `"results"`, my code could successfully parse the JSON response. Can any body explain how can I deal with this problem. The program should be able to extract the array elements without I manually remove the lines as I did to debug.

Comment: What is JsonObject and JsonParser, What kind of parser u are using?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to get parse your JSON response. you can obtain array at resultArray,

```
try{
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(JSONresponse);
JSONObject bossObj = obj.getJSONObject("bossresponse");
JSONObject webObj = obj.getJSONObject("web");
JSONArray resultArray obj = obj.getJSONArray("results");
for(i=0;i<=resultArray.length();i++){
JSONObject resultObject = resultArray.getJSONObject(i);
String date = resultObject.getString("date");
String clickurl = resultObject.getString("clickurl");
String url = resultObject.getString("url");
String dispurl= resultObject.getString("dispurl");
String title = resultObject.getString("title");
String abstract = resultObject.getString("abstract");
}
} catch (Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to read results from web attribute, not just wrapper top object, 
So: this is your `linksObject`:

```
JsonObject linksObj =  jsonParser.parse(jsonReader).getAsJsonObject();
```

It should have `bossresponse` attribut, and it is another object.
from `bossresponse` object you will have `web` object
from `web` you will have `results` object

`bossresponse->web->results`

now you are kind a reading `results` from first level. I guess It would work if json is

```
{
results:[
   {
     //here attrs
   }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I do this in Java.

Comment: Can you print `linksObj.get("bossresponse").toString()`?

Comment: No. I get: Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Array.
at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonArray(JsonElement.java:99)
at parseResponse.main(parseResponse.java:35)`.

Comment: Of course `bossresponse` not array, in order to be array it should be []. I said json object like that: `JsonObject linksObj =  jsonParser.parse(jsonReader).getAsJsonObject();
`

Comment: Yes. It prints the whole JSON file content. How can I reach the `responses` array ?

Comment: Man It does not print whole json, `linksObj.get("bossresponse")`. It will return content of `bossresponse` attr, then from `linksObj.get("bossresponse")` object you will get `.get('web')`

Comment: `linkObj.getAsJsonObject("bossresponse").getAsJsonObject("web").getAsJsonArray('results')`; This should be fine